How can this Clapp JFET oscillate when its gate is tied to ground at the resonance frequency?
How does the circuit below oscillate? It seems to have |gain| < 1 at its oscillation frequency of 2.25 MHz, yet it oscillates there.

My analysis:

The DC path is through L4 only, allowing a bias source current which the datasheet seems to suggest should be less than 5mA, but seems to be closer to 9mA
Near 2.25 MHz, L1 + C2 have no impedance, so the gate should be connected directly to ground and not move, even if the source moves.  But the opposite seems to happen! It resonates at around this frequency!
At other frequencies, I'd expect positive feedback and oscillation.  For example, at 1 MHz, L4 has impedance > 1k, so an increase in source current needs to go through C1 and C3.  A 1 uA increase in I_source amplitude at 1 MHz should cause about 200 uV increase in Vgs amplitude, which should further increase I_source, causing positive feedback.  But the circuit does not oscillate at 1 MHz!


Update
Partial answer: It indeed does not resonate at 2.25 MHz, where L1 + C2 have zero impedance.
Indeed, at 2.25 MHz, the gate is tied tightly to ground, and there will be no oscillation at all.
Instead, it resonates closer to 2.39 MHz, where C1 + L1 + C2 have impedance of 82j, and C4 has impedance close to -82j, giving a parallel impedance from the source to ground approaching infinity.  This means that current from the source at 2.39 Mhz has nowhere to go to get to ground: L4 is very high impedance, the gate has very high impedance, and the C4||(C1+L1+C2) network has very high impedance, causing the gate's voltage to go up, and giving very high gain.
Nonetheless, I'm still confused about how to understand this circuit, or predict the voltages or gains at different points, or why it doesn't resonate at other frequencies (which also seem to have sufficient gain).

No, L1 and C2 have about 1414 Ohms each at the indicated frequency. Where did you get the idea that their impedance is zero? It's just at a minimum with the impedance of L1 and the impedance of C2 exactly the same value. But that minimum, nor their separate impedances, is not zero.

@periblepsis I thought that they cancel out: ZL = -j1414, ZC = j1414, ZL+ZC (series) = 0.

@periblepsis Google seems to say the same thing: "A similar effect happens in series inductive/capacitive circuits. When a state of resonance is reached (capacitive and inductive reactances equal), the two impedances cancel each other out and the total impedance drops to zero!"

I see. Try placing an AC voltage source, at the given resonant frequency, across those two components and look at the current through the pair. Run it for 100 us, or so. Do you see infinite current? Or something else? What do you think Spice is doing here?

Look up Clapp oscillator

@periblepsis With a 1V amplitude (RMS 0.7V) 2.25MHz, I get 32mA RMS, or about 20 ohms, which is consistent with zero impedance at resonance (since 2.25 is not exact resonance).  I also built voltage dividers and measured voltage, and got similar results.

@Tesla23 If you look at the schematic, you'll see its labeled "Clapp".  My question is: How does a Clapp oscillator such as this oscillate?

It's a series resonant circuit where if you work out the impedance of C1, C3 and J1 you will find that it looks like C1 in series with C3 in in series with a negative resistance. If the total resistance in the series circuit is negative, it oscillates

I count 2.37MHz in the plotted waveform.

No DC path from gate to ground ?

Add only 10 Ohm serial with L1.

By re-arranging the resonating L's and C's, it may help understand where resonance occurs. The two arrangements shown are electrically equivalent:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

C4 combines with C5 & C6 to yield net capacitance of 44.117647 picofarads, which combines with L2 to be parallel-resonant at 2.396 MHz.
Splitting the resonating capacitance into three components gives design freedom that lets resonant Q to be high, in concert with the impedance of the sustaining oscillator transistor.
The Clapp oscillator works by injecting a sustaining current pulse into C6.

Solid State Design for the Radio Amateur suggests choosing the reactive components for a Clapp JFET oscillator:

\$XC_4 \approx 200\Omega\$
\$XC_5 = 45\Omega\$
\$XC_6 = 45\Omega\$
\$XL_2 \approx 260\Omega\$
FET source choke \$XL_{RFC} \approx 4500 \Omega\$


Thanks! Don't the Solid State Design for the Radio Amateur guidelines fail to resonate: $200j + 45j + 45j - 260j \neq 0$.

That's true. Perhaps real-world inductors (especially air-core) have extra capacitance to adjacent ground that boosts their reactance... in SSDR book, these four resonant components are shown enclosed in a grounded shielded enclosure. Clapp circuits, the inductor tends to be bigger than in other oscillator circuit types. The sustaining oscillator runs non-linearly - how those current pulses affect frequency isn't clear to me. You might treat these impedance recommendation as "rules of thumb".


How does the circuit below oscillate?

I have simulated this circuit with microcap v12.
Found that it oscillates when the serial resistor (R3 with 100 uH inductor) value is < ~ 30 Ohm.


Stability curves (Middlebrook) ...

The oscillation frequency is quite the value of "stability" curves at max point.
(2.35 MHz < frequency < 2.45 MHz) (30 Ohm is in "blue", just "limit" of oscillation).

